# How to draw position sign?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, ownerdrawn

I writing my own textbox control in C# for Winforms.

One thing i can't figure out: how to draw the text position sign in various sizes?

[image: Text position sign]

Comment: Why are you writing your own textbox control

Comment: @Matti: .NET owner-drawn controls are fun!

Comment: It's *extremely* hard to get an owner-drawn textbox to work right. And as soon as you start re-inventing the wheel like this, you'll notice that you're missing a lot of basic stuff you took for granted in the Windows implementation. Your control won't support right-to-left languages (not everyone in the world prefers to read English), you won't get IME support, and so on and so forth. So, seriously, reconsider whether you really want to roll your own textbox. If this is for anything other than personal learning purposes, the answer is **no**.

Comment: And, what's a "text position sign"? If you're talking about the *cursor*, then what's that triangle at the top of it in the picture you've shown?

Comment: The reason for custom textbox is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909179/tests-with-textbox-under-dwm-glass

Comment: @DxCK: Ah, yeah. But creating a custom textbox control is not the best solution. You're breaking approximately 94 other things just to fix one. The simplest way of doing that is setting `Application.SetCompatibleTextRendering` to `true`, which causes text to be drawing with GDI+, rather than GDI. Since GDI+ is alpha-aware, everything works fine. You'll find this in your `Main` method defined in `Program.cs`.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thanks, but this method doesn't affect textboxes, only labels.

Answer (score 2):

It is called the 'caret'.  The winapi functions are not wrapped by winforms, you'll have to pinvoke them.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646968%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You'll find code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539132/how-do-you-include-a-cursor-caret-in-a-custom-control).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I created a method which is meant to be called from the paint handler of whichever control you're drawing in. For simplicity I just used the form itself in mine. You probably have a panel or some other control.

The method accepts the graphics object, the scale of the cursor and the upper/left position of where to start drawing. The scale is just the height but all the math is performed relative to the height. You can tweak those numbers any way you want.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawCaret(e.Graphics, 30, new Point(20, 20));
        DrawCaret(e.Graphics, 50, new Point(100, 100));
    }

    private static void DrawCaret(Graphics g, int scale, Point loc)
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        int height = scale;
        int width = scale/10;
        int rectBase = scale/5;

        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, loc.X, loc.Y, width, height);

        var path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddPolygon(new[]
                            {
                                new Point(loc.X+width, loc.Y),
                                new Point(loc.X+width+rectBase/2, loc.Y+rectBase/2),
                                new Point(loc.X+width, loc.Y+rectBase),
                            });
        g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);
    }
```

This sample produces the following output:

[image: sample]

Comment: The 'cursor' is the arrow you move with the mouse.  He's talking about the caret, the vertical bar in a text box.

Comment: Yeah, I just recalled after reading your answer. Refactored the code sample accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with this method is that it doesn't support ClearType.

Comment: All you need for cleartype-style rendering is to set the `SmoothingMode` to `HighQuality`. That will perform nice anti-aliasing for you and make for a nice fit with clear type text. See line of code I added at the top of the DrawCaret method.

Comment: @DxCK: It can't possibly support ClearType. You're not drawing any text!